# Process communication with signals

Tags: operating-system, alarm, system-calls

I was programming in C doing system calls, and I was wondering the following:

What's an example of where you'd want a process to ignore alarm signals, say if the signal was sent because of a lost packet in intra-network processes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many *important* daemons are very picky about the signals they will respond to; they often install a handler for `SIGHUP` to re-read their configuration file, use one of `SIGUSR1` or `SIGUSR2` to indicate the need to close and re-open their log files for log-rotation, and handle `SIGINT`, `SIGQUIT`, `SIGTERM`, etc., in some sort of graceful way.

Everything else should be ignored so that accidental signals do not cause the program to do funny things. The signals that are part of the program's interface should work exactly as designed -- and the other signals should do as little harm as possible.